# How to sum string elements with lambda in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, lambda, int, addition

I need to sum every 2 elements (As int)

I have the following code :

```
array = '1 3 5 7 9'
lst = map(lambda x: x+x, array.strip().split(' '))
print(list(lst))
```

Output:

> ['11', '33', '55', '77', '99']

Is there a way to add int casting to the lambda/map function which will eventually will consider my lambada function as addition of 2 elements ?

I know i can make an Explicit function which will do that, but i want to know if there is a lambda way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to int in your function:

```
array = '1 3 5 7 9'
lst = map(lambda x: int(x)+int(x), array.strip().split(' '))
print(list(lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

By default is taking the values as a string, because the original value is a string. To apply any number operation just force the casting to an integer value, using `int(x)`

```
array = '1 3 5 7 9'
lst = map(lambda x: int(x) + int(x), array.strip().split(' '))
print(list(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read input number asking for the length of the list using input() or raw_input() .
Initialize an empty list lst = [] .
Read each number using a for loop .
In the for loop append each number to the list.
Now we use a predefined function sum() to find the sum of all the elements in a list.
Print the result.